# im facing problem while I upgrade My react app 0.64.2 to 0.71.3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, updates

I got 2 errors

97 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 93 up-to-date
error resolveDependencies: Found duplicate dependency key 'undefined' in C:\Project_Repo\App_Frontend\IndigoLearn\index.js

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleDevDebugJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I'm trying to update my app but its give me this build error

Answer (score 1):

You can set `enableHermes` to false in `android/app/built.gradle`.

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

Now clean your project and rebuild your project.